# Convert from a UIImage Transform to a CIImage transform

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image

I have a method of transforming an image with gestures (scale, rotation and translation).  The gestures modify a `CGAffineTransform` which is applied to an image view.  This works well.

```
self.imageView.transform = transform;
```

Now I want to use CoreImage (for various reasons):

```
CIImage *outputCIImage = [self.ciImage imageByApplyingTransform:transform];
CGImageRef cgImage = [self.context createCGImage:outputCIImage fromRect:self.imageView.bounds];
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```

However because CoreImage has a different co-ordinate system, the gestures are flipped in the Y axis:

- Zooming still works
- Panning left and right still works
- Panning up and down is flipped
- Rotating is reversed.

I can fix the gestures so that it all works by applying a this correction, as suggested by [this post](http://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/coreimage-and-uikit-coordinates.html):

[image]

```
CGAffineTransform flipYTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, self.view.bounds.size.height);
transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, flipYTransform);
```

[image]

However the whole image becomes flipped.  How can I convert the transform from UIImage to CoreImage?

Comment: Please tell me you've solved it. Me and my team are going CRAZY because of it. We'll give anything for a solution...